# Customizing output of JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the controller I have a respond_with like this:

```
respond_with(@layer1 , @layer2)
```

The JSON output I need is like this:

```
{
   "LayerOne": [
      {
         "name": "haha",
         "number":"44"
      }, // more .... 
   ],
  "LayerTwo": [
     {
        "name": "James Bond",
        "score": 20
     } // , ....
  ]
}
```

So to get the first section I write the serializer like this:

```
class Layer1Serializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :number, :name

  def name
    object.person.name
  end

end
```

And I change the controller to be like this, so I can pass a ROOT so it shows in the JSON as "LayerOne"

```
respond_with(@Layer1, root: 'LayerOne')
```

but remember at the beginning I had two things to pass to controller, so now I can't figure our how to do this for the second section of JSON that says "Layer2"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the following intermediate class:

```
class BothLayers
  include ActiveModel
  def initialize(layer1,layer2)
    @layer1 = layer1
    @layer2 = layer2
  end
  attr_accessor :layer1, :layer2
end
```

and the following serializer:

```
class BothLayersSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  root false
  has_many :layer1, key: "LayerOne"
  has_many :layer2, key: "LayerTwo"
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
    both_layers = BothLayers.new(@layer1,@layer2)
    respond_with( both_layers, serializer: BothLayersSerializer )
```

Comment: brilliant ..... haven't practically tried it yet but just reading what you have here sounds to be a correct solution...plesse update it if you find new tips or tricks about it too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

create a new hash and pass your array values into it.

```
respond_with({:LayerOne => @layer1.as_json(:only => [:name, :percentage]), :LayerTwo => @layer2.as_json(:only => [:name, :off_target_by])})
```

i got this json :

```
{
    "LayerOne": [
        {
            "name": "layer1",
            "percentage": "10.11"
        },
        {
            "name": "layer 1 bis",
            "percentage": "1212.0"
        }
    ],
    "LayerTwo": [
        {
            "name": "layer 2",
            "off_target_by": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "layer 2 bis",
            "off_target_by": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

hope it helps :)

EDIT 2 :

You can create an array serializer to pass your variables :

```
class LayerArraySerializer < ActiveModel::ArraySerializer
  self.root = false
end
```

and in your view :

```
respond_with({:LayerOne => @layer1 , :LayerTwo => @layer2}, :serializer => LayerArraySerializer)
```

json print :

```
[
    [
        "LayerOne",
        [
            {
                "percentage": "10.11",
                "name": "layer1"
            },
            {
                "percentage": "1212.0",
                "name": "layer 1 bis"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        "LayerTwo",
        [
            {
                "off_target_by": 2,
                "name": "layer 2"
            },
            {
                "off_target_by": 9,
                "name": "layer 2 bis"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Oh well this is not using Serializer, This is just the old style as_json .... I have better than that with JBuidler,  Here I wanted to evaluate Serializer,

Answer (score 1):

Using the JBuilder DSL is an excellent way to solve your problem.

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

The JSON response you want is implemented as a view, giving you complete control over how it renders.

Comment: Thanks, I already have written it in JBuilder, Wanted to evaluate Serializer and see how hard/easy is it in customizing stuff in compare ot JBuilder.

Comment: Well I guess you answered that question ;D

Answer (score 0):

Railcasts has an excellent video+text tutorial on AR Serializer, I'm sure you'll find your answer there

http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers

Comment: yep I have watched that, but couldn't solve the question I posted. Any ideas?